# Django 1.6: Generate html report file after running unit test cases

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I want to generate a html file after runnin django unti test cases. As i want to mail the report to my project team members at every unit test run or deploy you can say. Is there good approach to do it..?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) and this [tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/kmmbvnr/home/django-jenkins-tutorial).